# What is the range on the Shock Blast spell?

Tags: fantasy-age

There is no RAW range on the Lightning Arcana spell Shock Blast. Is the center of the spell on the caster, two squares away to allow for a full 3x3 area of effect, or is the spell able to be cast at a further range from the caster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the spell to the Hieromancy Arcana spell Suppression Bonds. If it wanted you to choose an area not adjacent to the caster it would say so. Based on the target selection of Suppression Bonds (being 8 yards) the area must only be adjacent to the starting point not centered on (this is different for circular areas like Fireball). As such, the effective range is 6 yards.